# Bigcommerce stencil additional payment checkout button is not displaying on quick cart and cart view page?

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce, stencils

On my store the payment additional button is not displaying like PayPal checkout with PayPal etc please check the screenshot:

[image: https://prnt.sc/jxace6]

it should look like this

[image: https://i.imgur.com/wjIHgga.png]

please help it's not showing HTML code when I am checking in inspect element

Comment: Hi. Are those payment methods enabled in the store Control Panel? Are you trying to add your own buttons and take payments with custom code/API?

Comment: The all set up from admin end but it's not showing with Braintree like if I disable the Braintree and enable PayPal to express then it showing but I need PayPal button with Braintree

Comment: Please get in touch with our support team. We will need to look into your payment settings which can include personal information. https://support.bigcommerce.com/contact

Comment: I have request them they just check base theme and always show the excuse that its working you can find the same question on bigcommerce community

Comment: What is the link to the forum question?

Comment: https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B00004SsHJbSAN/additional-payment-checkout-button-is-not-displaying-on-quick-cart-and-cart-view-page-?t=1529604184429&searchQuery=

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have fixed the issue
The problem original head scripts was missing

Thanks a lot